# Newbee JavaScript advice

Tags: javascript, html

I am an absolute newbee to javascript and I have these working on a web page.

HTML

```
<body>
   <p id="decrease">399.99</p>
   <button type="button" onclick="decrease();">Start Now!</button>
</body>
```

SCRIPT

```
var i=399.99;

function decrease()
{
i--;
document.getElementById('decrease').innerHTML= +i;
}
```

The script works when the button is clicked but decreases the number by "1" and I need it to decrease by 0.25 and I need a "$" sign in front of the number.

Can someone help?

Thanks everyone who responded it works perfectly no need for any other answers, Happy Holidays

Answer (score 4):

```js
var i = 399.99;

function decrease() {
  i -= 0.25;
  document.getElementById('decrease').innerHTML = "$" + i;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <p id="decrease">$399.99</p>
  <button type="button" onclick="decrease();">Start Now!</button>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var i = 399.99;

function decrease() {
  i -= 0.25;
  document.getElementById('decrease').innerHTML = '$'+i;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <p id="decrease">$399.99</p>
  <button type="button" onclick="decrease();">Start Now!</button>
</body>
```

Comment: @usandfriends I missed that.  Now fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Add a "$" to the innerHTML:

```
var i=399.99;

function decrease()
{
    i-=0.25;
    document.getElementById('decrease').innerHTML= '$' + +i;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/jjt5u1dn/2/

Comment: The OP says: `[...]and I need it to decrease by 0.25`

Answer (score 0):

Given that the `$` character is presentational, I'd suggest using CSS rather than JavaScript:

```
#decrease::before {
    content: "$";
}
```